# Cannot find mpm-itk after installing

Tags: apache2.4

I have installed mpm_itk using

```
apt-get install apache2-mpm-itk
```

But after installing, when I try to enable using

```
a2enmod mpm_itk
```

it says module is not found

At first I was using apache2.4.10, I tried to shift to 2.4.7 but same problem. I am on ubuntu 14.04

Help on how to solve.

Comment: By any chance do you have mpm_prefork mod installed ?

Comment: yes it is installed @Ten-Coin

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `mpm_prefork` installed then it may cause issues while enabling `mpm_itk`.

So disable `mpm_prefork` and then try enabling or try reinstalling `mpm_itk`.

```
# a2dismod mpm_prefork
# a2enmod mpm_itk
```

**EDIT: Installation**

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk
```

Then try

```
a2enmod mpm_itk
```

You have choose proper package to install it seems , observe the below log

```
Setting up libapache2-mpm-itk (2.4.7-04-1) ...
apache2_invoke: Enable module mpm_itk
root@openstackm1:~# a2enmod mpm_itk
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for mpm_itk:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Module mpm_itk already enabled
root@openstackm1:~#
```

Comment: it didn't work, the apache2 failed to restart, it says: `AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded` . It seems mpm_itk is not part of default distribution, when i install manually, it cannot be found in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. I don't know where does it go. That is why it kept saying: `cannot find module`

Comment: give us complete activity logs. It will help us understanding the issue. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is not `mpm_prefork`. The issue is that after installing `mpm_itk` it goes somewhere else and not in: `/etc/apache2/sites-available` so no matter how i try to enable it with: `a2enmod mpm_itk` it never gets found. Now i where did it go after installation. Any idea please! @Ten-Coin

Comment: This is the output i get this time when i try to edit the installation: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.` @Ten-Coin

Comment: And the problem proceeds

Comment: The issue is to know where it goes to after being installed then enable if from there @Ten-Coin

Comment: @SamuelThomas This is not complete information. We need complete information what you have typed and what you got. This wont help us understanding your issue.

Comment: I typed : `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk` as super user, and the output was:
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mpm-itk is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  liblua5.1-0
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.` @Ten-Coin

Comment: @SamuelThomas and what you got when you tried while enabling ? Give us complete output here

Comment: While enabling I typed: `a2enmod mpm_itk` and the output was: `ERROR: Module mpm_itk does not exist!` @Ten-Coin

Comment: Is your apache running right now ?

Comment: yes it is running @Ten-Coin

Comment: can you try restarting it  and give us the complete log here

Comment: @SamuelThomas It's not supposed to be installed/referenced in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` it should be in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`. Try purging and re-installing the module. `sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mpm-itk && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mpm-itk` and then try to enable it again.

Comment: To restart I typed: `service apache2 restart` and the output was: ` * Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]`

Comment: Seems all good now ? And yes always installed mods will be at mods-available , hence the name

Comment: @Dan i made a mistake i meant: `/etc/apache2/mods-available`

Comment: @Dan @Ten-Coin and it is not in mods-available either. if it were, it could have easily been found when i ran: `a2enmod mpm_itk` and there could be no errors

Comment: The problem is still there, I still cannot enable the module although i have already installed it. @Ten-Coin

Comment: Look at the output when i try to list all files starting with **mpm_** in  `/etc/apache2/mods-available`, i typed: `ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_` then pressed tab and here was the output: `mpm_event.conf    mpm_prefork.conf  mpm_worker.conf   
mpm_event.load    mpm_prefork.load  mpm_worker.load` and you can see that mpm_itk is not among them, so it means it was installed to a different location,  and i wonder which that is! @Dan @Ten-Coin